Solana logsSubscribe (Websocket Method)
My goals is to monitor each token's transactions (buys/sells) on Raydium, live.
For that I use "logsSubscribe" WS method that returns ray_logs
Example JSON 'ray_log' decoded:
    {
  "name": "swapBaseIn",
  "data": {
    "logType": 3,
    "amountIn": "21514983692",
    "minimumOut": "0",
    "direction": "1",
    "userSource": "21514983692",
    "poolCoin": "140696852628033375",
    "poolPc": "21316786476678",
    "outAmount": "141507531909869"
  }
}

First way: Subscribe to Raydium's LiquidityPoolV4 program (main AMM that will be streaming every transaction that is happening on Raydium) and then filter & sort these transactions. Problem with this way is logs don't contain Mint address of a token being involved.
Example of single output from 'logsSubscribe' method:
(https://i.sstatic.net/51pCQNfH.png)
Second way: Subscribe to each individual liquidity pool (pair) and monitor its logs. But say there are 2000+ pairs. Is it too many concurrent WS subscriptions opened OR might actually just be a scale problem?
Any help appreciated, thank yall!
Tired using 'logSubscribe' on LiquidityPoolV4: no Mint addresses are found in logs, i don't know what token these logs belong to.
